# Sorting an array of object, then setText with if else

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, arraylist

i have sorted an array with double value

```
Arrays.sort(banding);
```

then i want to setText with the highest value that have specific String value "CUKUP". If it's not "CUKUP" than it's must be "LEBIH" and i don't want any "LEBIH" String value as an output

```
        if (banding[6].getKetTotal().equals("CUKUP")) {
            untungtertinggi.setText(Double.toString(banding[6].harga));
        } else if (banding[6].getKetTotal().equals("LEBIH")) {
            if (banding[5].getKetTotal().equals("CUKUP")) {
                untungtertinggi.setText(Double.toString(banding[5].harga));
            }
        }else if (banding[5].getKetTotal().equals("LEBIH")) {
            if (banding[4].getKetTotal().equals("CUKUP")) {
                untungtertinggi.setText(Double.toString(banding[4].harga));
            }
        }else if (banding[4].getKetTotal().equals("LEBIH")) {
            if (banding[3].getKetTotal().equals("CUKUP")) {
                untungtertinggi.setText(Double.toString(banding[3].harga));
            }
        }else if (banding[3].getKetTotal().equals("LEBIH")) {
            if (banding[2].getKetTotal().equals("CUKUP")) {
                untungtertinggi.setText(Double.toString(banding[2].harga));
            }
        }else if (banding[2].getKetTotal().equals("LEBIH")) {
            if (banding[1].getKetTotal().equals("CUKUP")) {
                untungtertinggi.setText(Double.toString(banding[1].harga));
            }
        }else if (banding[1].getKetTotal().equals("LEBIH")) {
            if (banding[0].getKetTotal().equals("CUKUP")) {
                untungtertinggi.setText(Double.toString(banding[0].harga));
            }
        }
```

this coding is still wrong because when all arrays have String value "CUKUP" it doesn't put the highest double value as an output

Comment: If you have sorted the array, why not walk the array (probably backwards), and check if the value is `CUKUP` or `LEBIH`. You can then simplify the logic.

Comment: Are you sure the sorting is working as expected, I am asking because if all items contains CUKUP then the first if should have outputted the right value?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson when i sort the array and check it 1by1 its correct. but when i put an if condition its doesnt work as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear what is supposed to be output if the checks fail, so I'm guessing `0.0`, but it could be adjusted.

The approach, if I followed the OP's logic, can be condensed to a loop, reducing the amount of checking. The specific object type of the array `banding` was not specified, so I haphazardly used `Banding` as the object type -- that is probably not exactly correct.

NOTE: the assumption is that the array is properly sorted.

```
Arrays.sort(banding);
setText(banding);

void setText(Banding[] banding) {
  final int loc = banding.length - 1;

  // if the highest is what we want, set and return
  if (banding[loc].getKekTotal().equals("CUKUP")) {
    untungtertinggi.setText(Double.toString(banding[loc].harga));
    return;
  }


  // we run until one before the start of the array, as we check for the 
  //   previous value; if we meet the criteria of [i] being LEBIH, and [i - 1]
  //   being CUKUP, then we set the value and return
  for (int i = loc; i > 0; --i) {
    if (banding[i].getKekTotal().equals("LEBIH") &&
         banding[i - 1].getKetTotal().equals("CUKUP")) {
      untungtertinggi.setText(Double.toString(banding[i - 1].harga));
      return;
    }
  }

  // no specific value found
  untuntertinggi.setText(Double.toString(0.0));
}
```